# What is known about gaps between zeros of L-functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

In many different settings, it is possible to determine statistics about spacings (pair correlation, small gaps, large gaps, champions, etc.), for instance

- prime numbers
- Laplacian eigenvalues on a lattice
- zeros of L-functions

In the latter setting, there are an expansive literature about correlations between zeros of L-functions, but what is known or attempted concerning the other problems (I have in mind essentially small and large gaps)?

Answer (score 3):

**Large gaps:** there is the striking result that the gap size is bounded, see [The largest gap between zeros of entire L-functions is less than 41.54](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X16307934) (2017).

**Small gaps:** according to [arXiv:1202.2671](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2671) there exist many Dirichlet L-functions that have a pair of consecutive zeros closer together than 0.37 times their average spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Typing "gaps between zeros of Selberg class" on Google gives as the fifth research result a survey by Caroline Turnage-Butterbaugh that may be helpful.